# Perl Term::Readline for multiple terminal history

Tags: perl, readline

I would like to use Term::ReadLine for two streams with separate historys.  Is this possible?  When I use the code below with two separate 'terminals' the history gets mixed together and when I look at the Attribs hash returned by $term _1->Attribs and $term_2->Attribs, the debugger says they use the same memory location.  The add_history function called in both cases is the same Gnu XS function and it doesn't take an option for a buffer as far as I can tell.
Is this possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
binmode(STDIN, 'utf8');
binmode(STDOUT, 'utf8');
# turn off underline on prompt.
$ENV{"PERL_RL"} = "o=0";

use Term::ReadLine;

my $term_1 = Term::ReadLine->new('term 1');
$term_1->enableUTF8();
my $OUT_1 = $term_1->OUT || \*STDOUT;

my $term_2 = Term::ReadLine->new('term 2');
$term_2->enableUTF8();
my $OUT_2 = $term_2->OUT || \*STDOUT;

# my $attrs =  $term_1->Attribs();
# for my $key (sort keys %{$attrs}) {
#     printf("%15s : %s\n", $key, $attrs->{$key});
# }
my $i_1 = 1;
my $i_2 = 1;
while (1) {
    $_ = $term_1->readline(sprintf("T 1:%2d > ", $i_1++));
    $term_1->addhistory($_) if /\S/;
    print $OUT_1 "\"$_\"\n";
    exit() if $_ eq 'q';

    $_ = $term_2->readline(sprintf("T 2:%2d > ", $i_2++));
    $term_2->addhistory($_) if /\S/;
    print $OUT_2 "\"$_\"\n";
    exit() if $_ eq 'q';
}
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 with perl 5, version 26.

Thanks

Comment: The `addhistory()` calls `add_history()` in `libreadline.so` which has the history as a static variable in the file [`history.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/history.c#n74). This means that this function does not support multiple histories for a given process. But two different processes will have different histories (since the static variables are separate).

Comment: Note: the above was for backend package `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`, I have not checked the other backends

Comment: In `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` there are functions `clear_history()` and `SetHistory()`. Maybe these can be used to simulate two separate histories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the backend [`Term::ReadLine::Gnu`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu#History-Functions) you can use `clear_history()` and `SetHistory()` to emulate two separate histories. For example:

```
my @hist1;
my @hist2;
while (1) {
    $term_1->clear_history();
    $term_1->SetHistory(@hist1);
    $_ = $term_1->readline(sprintf("T 1:%2d > ", $i_1++));
    push @hist1, $_ if /\S/;
    print $OUT_1 "\"$_\"\n";
    exit() if $_ eq 'q';
    $term_2->clear_history();
    $term_2->SetHistory(@hist2);
    $_ = $term_2->readline(sprintf("T 2:%2d > ", $i_2++));
    push @hist2, $_ if /\S/;
    print $OUT_2 "\"$_\"\n";
    exit() if $_ eq 'q';
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am embarrsed to admit I missed the gnu readline docs.  Also you don't seem to need to do the clear history.